# Is it correct to say "the truth is" when the rest of the sentence is in the past?

Tags: grammar, verbs, american-english, tenses, verb-agreement

Is it correct to say:

The truth **is**, he **was** a great explorer.

Or do I have to say:

The truth **was**, he **was** a great explorer.

Or are both okay?

Comment: Both are OK but depend on the context perspective (present/past): Michael didn't know anything about John. The truth WAS, John WAS a great explorer.

Answer (score 2):

The simple present is used to express time-neutral, general truths, a usage called the *universal* or [*gnomic*](https://www.thoughtco.com/gnomic-present-verbs-1690902) present. Long before [*gnome*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gnome) referred to some earth-dwelling spirit or, later, garden statuary in questionable taste, *gnomic* meant ‘didactic, concerned with maxims or aphorisms’, which are often couched in the simple present. This meaning was extended to general truths and opinions held to be universally acknowledged:

> A stitch in time *saves* nine.
>   At sea level, water *boils* at 100°C.
>   Sarah Bernhardt [*is*](https://wfpp.cdrs.columbia.edu/pioneer/sarah-bernhardt/) the most famous actress of the late nineteenth century stage. — Women Film Pioneers Project

To say that Sarah Bernhardt *was* the most famous actress of the late nineteenth century stage expresses the same fact, but anchors it to the timeframe of the narrative, presumably to the late 19th c., rather than holding it forth as a universally held opinion not bound to time.

Thus both of your example sentences are idiomatic and grammatical, the only difference is what aspect — time-neutral or bound — you wish the statement to convey. If this explorer is no longer well-known, then the past tense would be more appropriate; if still a famous person, then the gnomic present is a commonly used option.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely fine, and I'd be hard-pressed to find an example sentence where "the truth was" would be appropriate. The truth generally doesn't change, and even if he's a mediocre explorer now, it's still true that he was.

Compare:

> I think he didn't do it.

He didn't do it in the past, but I'm convinced of it in the present, so the tenses don't need to agree.

Comment: A truth that was discovered at, or relevant to, a past event could be discussed using the past tense. The man who married my sister told her he worked in a bank, but the truth was that he was a gangster.

Comment: Basically, when the "truth" is unknown in the timeframe being discussed but becomes known at a later time, you might describe that with "the truth was".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Spot on.  For example (this is not a direct quotation), “Brutus and his co-conspirators claimed the restoration of republican liberty as the justification for Caesar’s assassination:  the truth was that Brutus was heavily invested in the tax farming that Caesar was planning to regulate properly, to end the rampant profiteering and extortion.”.   Here the use of ‘was’ casts doubt about Brutus’ honesty.  If

Comment: @MichaelHarvey If the present had been used, it would be taken as mainly a statement about what the (present) historian thinks the truth ‘is’ about what happened.  But the difference is marginal.